# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Snapshot Replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication

I have a question on Snapshot replication on SQL Server 2008 R2.

My subscribers are in push mode.

Currently, the replication works, but during the replication, the request SELECT on subscriber works too.

In SQL Profiler, I saw the request are in transaction (drop table, create table and bulk insert). But i can SELECT table during request and during transaction.

I tried Snapshot Isolation on TRUE and False and READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT on TRUE and False and doesn't work too.

Why subscriber allow SELECT on table during replication and how deny this ?

In advance, thanks for your help and for your reply.

Comment: Snapshot isolation will allow select to read a table as it was before the  transaction. It's won't stop you reading, it will _allow_ you to read. You don't have `WITH (NOLOCK)` in your select do you?

Comment: I don't have WITH(NOLOCK) on my select too. 

Normally, SQL Server allow SELECT after replication is done, no ?